# microsoft speech recognition + nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

Is the nodejs cognitive services speech sdk still supported? I know how to do this for the browser based sdk, but it looks like the nodejs version doesn't work, it doesn't capture any microphone input.

Notably, there are no examples publish that use `AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput` for nodejs. The nodejs sdk works perfectly fine with `AudioConfig.fromStreamInput`

Here's the relevant code:

```
var speechsdk = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");
var subscriptionKey = ";)";
var serviceRegion = "eastus"; // e.g., "westus"

const speech_Config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(subscriptionKey, serviceRegion, "en-US");
const audioConfig = speechsdk.AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
let speech_recognizer= new speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_Config, audioConfig);

speech_recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(
    function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        speech_recognizer.close();
        speech_recognizer = undefined;
    },
    function (err) {
        console.trace("err - " + err);
        speech_recognizer.close();
        speech_recognizer = undefined;
 });
```

I get an error saying: `window is not defined`

npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this error , Microsoft engineers has an explain for it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/cognitive-services-speech-sdk-js/issues/21) .

> It is due to the default microphone support uses the Web Audio API to
>   conjure a microphone stream. The node environment doesn't support
>   this.
>
> As a workaround , for pure node code you can use a file, push or pull
>   stream to get audio into the speech recognition engine.

Hope it helps : )

Comment: May I know is it helpful ?